# Cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field * of type pgtype.Range[github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype.Date]

Tags: go, unmarshalling, pgx

I have problems to scan json objects which include daterange types:

Let's assume these tables:

```
CERATE TABLE first_table (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CERATE TABLE second_table (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  title text,
  period daterange NOT NULL,
  a_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES first_table (id)
);
```

The structs are

```
type A struct {
  ID int
  Name *string
  SomeBs []B
}

type B struct {
  ID int
  Title *string
  Period  pgtype.Range[pgtype.Date]
}
```

The query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    bs.*
FROM first_table a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
    COALESCE(json_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', id,
        'title', title,
        'period', period)), '[]')
    FROM second_table b 
    WHERE a.id = b.a_id
) AS bs ON true
```

I get the error `can't scan into dest[2]: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field B.Period of type pgtype.Range[github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype.Date]`

As writte [here](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/1374), scanning it without `json_agg` and `json_build_object`, it works.
If for testing purpose I changed the type B.Period to string, the query works and the value is something like `[2020-02-01,2023-02-03)`. I tried to change the type to `date_range.DateRange` or `pgtype.Range[differentTypes]`, nothing worked.

How can I scan the values in `date_range.DateRange` or `pgtype.Range[pgtype.Date]`? I would prefer the latter.